# UWSGI and NGINX for Python Apps on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, python, wsgi, uwsgi

I am trying to find an optimal way to set up my server to use NGINX and UWSGI to serve python applications. The following has worked so far:

**Initial setup:**

```
sudo apt-get install nginx uwsgi uwsgi-plugin-http uwsgi-plugin-python python-setuptools

easy_install pip

pip install web.py
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;
    }
}
```

**And then I have a basic myapp.py (location doesn't matter for the current setup):**

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello from Web.py!"

application = app.wsgifunc()
```

**Then I can issue the following commands and everything works:**

```
sudo service nginx restart

uwsgi --plugins http,python -s 127.0.0.1:9090 myapp
```

So it works, but it's not very pretty. I noticed that when I installed UWSGI with `apt-get` that two directories were created: `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available` and `/etc/uqsgi/apps-enabled`. This matches the convention for debian servers running NGINX or Apache only with `apps` instead of `sites`.

Here is what would be awesome: I would like to be able to drop in application configurations to `apps-available` (creating symlinks in `apps-enabled` as needed) and have the UWSGI service pick them up. But I don't quite know where to start. What configuration files do I put in `apps-available`? And what does the NGINX configuration look like for passing to the uwsgi service rather than passing to the socket created by the command I issued earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working! Here's what I did:

**Created /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/myapp.xml:**

```
<uwsgi>
    <socket>/tmp/uwsgi-myapp.sock</socket>
    <plugins>http, python</plugins>
    <chdir>/path/to/directory/containing/python/app</chdir>
    <module>myapp</module><!-- myapp.py from before -->
</uwsgi>
```

**Issued the following commands:**

```
ln -s /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/myapp.xml /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.xml
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

**Updated /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi-myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

**Restarted NGINX:**

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

And everything is golden! Obviously, the above is a very simple configuration and one should review the availalbe UWSGI and NGINX options before going to production.

What also worked is in the UWSGI configuration having `<socket>127.0.0.1:9090</socket>` and leaving the NGINX configuration as it was.

As a final note: UWSGI supports multiple formats for configuration: (INI, XML, and YAML). I had originally tried YAML but the server would fail to start so I tried XML and everything worked fine.

**EDIT:**

I just tried INI configuration and it worked as well. The equivilant INI file as the XML file above is as follows:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/uwsgi-myapp.sock
plugins = http, pythong
chdir = /path/to/directory/containing/python/app
module = myapp
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This is just what I've been looking for. However, I've followed these instructions from a fresh install and now when I visit the root of my site with a browser I get a '502: Bad Gateway' nginx error. I'm using Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu 11.10: would this require further configuration?

Comment: Update: nginx's error.log said `connect() to unix:///tmp/uwsgi-myapp.sock failed: No such file or directory.` Does this mean that the socket isn't being created? If so, why not?

Comment: Try listing the contents of `/tmp` (`ls /tmp`) after you restart uwsgi. If it's not there then check the uswsgi logs to see what's up.